# I don't understand the Rank–nullity theorem..

Tags: intuition, vector-space-isomorphism

$$\dim(U) = \dim (\ker\phi) + \dim(\text{im }\phi)$$

Hey all I'm just a little confused about the above mentioned theorem; namely, how does one measure the dimensions of a kernel? A kernel is normally defined as a set, and I don't see how I could measure the dimensions of a set.. and surely, if we were referring to a bijection in the above-mentioned linear mapping, $\phi$, then wouldn't the theorem no longer hold true at that point because the dimensions of the ker would surely be 1, as there is definitely exactly one identity-element mapped to the identitity element in the other set, right? $n = 1 + n$?

a one-to-one mapping implies a Kernel with only one element and a set with only one element has how many dimensions? it sounds like I'm comparing apples to pears..

I hope it doesn't come across as a stoopid question, thanks yo.

Comment: The kernel of a linear transformation $T$ is a subspace of the domain of $T$, so, like any vector space, it has a dimension. When the kernel is trivial (just the zero vector), its dimension is $0$, not $1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott oh noeeeess, that's exactly it, thanks, facking trivial kernelzz

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing cardinality and dimension.  The set $\{0\}$ in a vector space has cardinality $1$, because it has one element, but it has dimension $0$.  A $1$-dimensional space is a line, while $\{0\}$ is a single-point space.

Comment: @JairTaylor yea you're right, if a kernel contains just the zero-vector - which in itself has dim = 0 - then the kernel also has dim = 0.. I read the kernel definition on wikipedia and it was referred to as a set so I figured cardinality would be the only property which could act as the set-equivalent of dim...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A kernel is not only a set, it is a subspace of $U$. Which is to say, it is itself a vector space, and as such has a notion of dimension.

It is actually a good exercise to show that this is indeed the case.

Comment: urghhh, why are the secrets of linear algebra being passed down so haphazardly, I constantly have to check the validity of my knowledge against secondary resources, there's no end to thiiiiiiiis... so in the case of isomorphic vectors, $dim(U)$ must be equal to $dim(Im\phi)$
thanks a bunch !